# Chrome Extension: How to make url.hostname a string so it can be used as a key in a dictionary?

Tags: javascript, string, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm saving visited domains into a dictionary by doing (relevant excerpt of my code):

```
const url = require('url');
let domainDict = {};
let currentDomain;

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabid, changeInfo, tab){
    chrome.tabs.query({'active' : true, 'currentWindow': true}, function(tabs){
        let newUrl = new URL(tabs[0].url);
        currentDomain = newUrl.hostname;
        domainDict[currentDomain] = currentTimer;
    });
});
```

which makes `console.log(domainDict);` print out only `[object Object]` no matter how many domains I add to the dictionary. Oddly enough, I am able to seemingly pull out the correct value using the right domain key, but I get a warning that each key needs to be unique, and I get the bug that makes it when I try to map through and render the dictionary, it renders every key value pair on every iteration.

I've tried `currentDomain = url.format(newUrl.hostname)` and even implementing an attempt of using a function to stringify it:

```
currentDomain = urlToString(url.hostname)

function urlToString(url) {
    return "Domain: " + url;
}
```

but both those solutions give all the same issues and bugs.

Comment: 1) no need for chrome.tabs.query, simply use changeInfo.url when it's present 2) `url` is just a string, not an URL object so you need to convert via `new URL(changeInfo.url).hostname`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the description, it does not seem to be a problem with `currentDomain`,nor with `url.hostname`. What is happening is that the Chrome console is printing your dictionary in a format that is not useful to you.

Try something like:

```
console.log('My dict ', domainDict);
```

Or

```
console.log(JSON.stringfy(domainDict));
```

And you should see that the dictionary and its keys are correct.

Comment: Ah, `console.log(JSON.stringfy(domainDict)); ` did allow me to correctly see everything was as it should be in the dictionary. Which means my bug of rendering every key value pair on each map iteration is a bug over in the rendering function and not in adding them to the dictionary. I'll start looking that over now. Thank you very much!